# How to animate scroll position? How to scroll smoothly?

Tags: android, animation, scroll, drawing

I wish to move smoothly to next scroll position in my custom view (on button press or event). How to implement this? First of all I can't see scroll animation class (only alpha, rotate, scale and translate). Secondly, having animation class, I can't see iterative one (say to scroll 100 pixels rights whatever position we have) only absolute ones (i.e. to animate from one constant value to another).

Answer (score 46):

Assuming you are using a ScrollView, does smoothScrollTo(...) work for you?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Should I use `ScrollView`? I am using `MyClass extends View` now.

Comment: I think it depends on what you are doing, if a ScrollView works for you then definetly use it.

Comment: I have tried extending `ScrollView` but found that `onScrollChanged()` doesn't called in the case. I need this method to be called since I calculate some parameters in it. I.e. `smoothScroll` doesn't work for me.

Comment: I assume you have subclassed ScrollView and overriden onScrollChanged?

Comment: This also works in a `RecyclerView`, with `smoothScrollToPosition()`.

Comment: Smooth scroll isn't so smooth. I am using @anton46's answer as that allows you to specify the duration of the scrool: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21574048/1617737

Answer (score 39):

Using `ObjectAnimator`, this is a sample for scrolling to top:

```
public void scrollToTop() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    ObjectAnimator xTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScrollView, "scrollX", x);
    ObjectAnimator yTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScrollView, "scrollY", y);

    AnimatorSet animators = new AnimatorSet();
    animators.setDuration(1000L);
    animators.playTogether(xTranslate, yTranslate);

    animators.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    animators.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Animating scroll is done through a combination of using **Scroller/OverScroller** (to compute the time interpolated values of your scroll offsets), **GestureDetectors** (to start the scroller object) and the **onComputeScroll** method of a View (which implicitly is your animation loop).

The official android docs now have a detailed tutorial on precisely this topic. http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html

Comment: that is explaining how to implement a ScrollView from scratch! that's not the answer

Answer (score 0):

See the [view_cache_demo](https://github.com/ldo/view_cache_demo_android) sample code to see how to do animated scrolling. It works in 2D, caches complex drawing and also handles fling gestures, but you can simplify all that as necessary.