# Android animation when scroll

Tags: android

I want do a animate scroll like Jquery´s (in this web page works when you click in top menu´s options) in android. is it possible? I have seen that exists scrollTo but is possible to do with animation and not like jumps. Thank you very much.

Comment: are you using ListView ?

Comment: no, I am not using ListView. I use scrollview with layouts

Comment: Duplicate of this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621439/how-to-animate-scroll-position-how-to-scroll-smoothly

Comment: Is there a good tutorial or example of smoothScrollTo for android?

Answer (score 0):

Using ObjectAnimator, This is a sample for scrolling to top :

```
public void scroolToTop() {
                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;
        ObjectAnimator xTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScrollView, "scrollX", x);
        ObjectAnimator yTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScrollView, "scrollY", y);

        AnimatorSet animators = new AnimatorSet();
        animators.setDuration(1000L);
        animators.playTogether(xTranslate, yTranslate);
        animators.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        animators.start();
    }
```