# Auto scrolling with specific speed

Tags: java, android, scrollbar

I have many views in an activity. I want to scroll from bottom to up in 5 seconds (or a specific time) how can I do that ? Also I tried the method below but I think this is not enough to do that.

```
myscrolview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myscrolview.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21574048/6759241) for a good technique.

Comment: @greeble31  Thanks man it worked perfect.